# Sizing the fontsize of a webview in a common way

Tags: android, webview, text-size

Actually I set the textsize of a webview as follow:

```
WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.LARGEST);
```

I set the TextSize from `WebSettings.TextSize.LARGEST` to `WebSettings.TextSize.SALLEST` depending on settings in a options-gui, so the user can choose the Textsize.

Now the Question:
But I think that WebSettings.TextSize.LARGEST is still too small on devices with a diagonal inch > 7.

So I want to scale the size a bit larger, but I don't know how to do this in a common way.

I mean I could set the DefaultFontSize of the webview directly, but I guess this will not scale correctly for all devices.

The question in code: I can't do:

```
 webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.LARGEST * 1.5f);
```

Any hints how you do this ?

Comment: `webSettings.setTextSize` takes argument only as `TextSize` which is a `enum`. So you can not use a scale factor with `TextSize` . Have a look at [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694306/how-to-set-text-size-in-webview-in-android).

Comment: Yes I know. I am looking for a common solution to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

`webSettings.setTextSize` is deprecated. I suggest you to try something like that :

```
int fontSize = webSettings.getDefaultFontSize();
int customFontSize = (int)(fontSize * 1.5);

webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(customFontSize);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Do you thing that getDefaultFontSize is depending on the device. I mean bigger devices will have bigger default text size ?

Comment: I think `getDefaultFontSize` depend on the accessibility option.