# Why do css properties change in android webview

Tags: android, css, webview

I find Android's web view behaviour strange when handling with css properties:

When displaying a web page that contains the following css properties: `font-size` and `line-height`set to:

```
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 35px;
```

Android's webview changes the properties to:

```
font-size: 17.4px;
line-height: 30.45px;
```

Why?

Comment: It might be of an extra settings for font-size or zoom. Even in browser, general settings, accessibility settings, display settings, android general font-size settings etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set text size in WebView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694306/how-to-set-text-size-in-webview-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer:

Just webView must be to set text size to "NORMAL" in android. Like this:

```
webView.getSettings().setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.NORMAL);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to find why this was happening. Btw Deprecated, Use webView.getSettings().setTextZoom(100); This will override the system font size on android webview to keep as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check page behavior in different resolutions? There might be defined `@media` rules in CSS, which change the style for different resolutions, for example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    p {
        font-size:20px;
        line-height:35px
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    p {
        font-size:17.4px;
        line-height:30.45px
    }
}
```

Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp).

Comment: Set this properties in element self style without defined media.
In tablet and also in mobile chrome browser work true. but in application in mobile work wrong!

Comment: Try also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796176/how-to-change-the-fontsize-in-an-android-webview)