# Apply font change to webview content loaded via external url

Tags: android, css, http, webview, styles

I need to render a HTTP URL to Web View and I need to customise the font family and size. How can I do this?

Comment: You can do it by injecting the javascripts in webview

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694306/how-to-set-text-size-in-webview-in-android

Comment: Check this answer : https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/7395170

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava that is for a local html file

Comment: Anu did you find the solution for this? I m trying to solve this issue also. Help me if you solved it!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018540/inject-css-to-a-site-with-webview-in-android (Is this the answer we both looking for? )